# Coffeescript class namespaced methods

Tags: javascript, oop, coffeescript

```
 class SocialStudies
      constructor : (@val1,@val2) ->
          console.log 'constructed '+@val1+' | '+@val2
      doAlerts :
          firstAlert : =>
               alert @val1
          secondAlert : =>
               alert @val2

 secondPeriod = new SocialStudies 'git to class!', 'no recess for you!'

 secondPeriod.doAlerts.firstAlert() // error this.val1 is not defined
```

Hopefully you get the idea. I would like to access `@val1` from a method set inside a method, and fat arrow does nothing! Does anyone know what to do here?

Comment: its trying to get @val1 on doalerts

Comment: I know. But how do I get @val1 from the class root?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 class SocialStudies
      constructor : (@val1,@val2) ->
          console.log 'constructed '+@val1+' | '+@val2
          @doAlerts =
            firstAlert : =>
                alert @val1
            secondAlert : =>
                alert @val2
```

Comment: That worked (upvote). Is it the only way? I don't see the big difference between your answer and what I had before.

Comment: your way if you looked at generated code would just generate the prototype, it had no way of capturing the "this".  Because I moved it to the constructor, I now have a "this" available to capture.

Comment: @Fresheyeball: Your `=>` would bind the two functions to the SocialStudies class itself since `@` would be the class in that context.

Comment: @muistooshort no, a fat arrow is not enough to bind to the SocialStudies class in my example. Keith already explained why, its been tested and accepted.

Comment: @Fresheyeball: I think you're misunderstanding what I'm saying. I'm not saying that Keith is wrong, I'm telling you why your code didn't work; look at the generated JavaScript and see what `@` ends up being inside your `firstAlert`.

Comment: @muistooshort I know why it doesn't work. What am I looking for is elegant solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can, of course, do it also like this:

```
class SocialStudies
  constructor: (@val1, @val2) ->
    @doAlerts = firstAlert: @firstAlert, secondAlert: @secondAlert
  firstAlert: =>
    alert @val1
  secondAlert: =>
    alert @val2
```

This it otherwise equivalent to Keith Nicholas' answer, but allows using the **super** keyword in the methods in inherited classes, so you could do, say, like this:

```
class AntiSocialStudies extends SocialStudies
  secondAlert: =>
    @val2 += ' no solitary drinking until 3PM.'
    super

secondPeriod = new AntiSocialStudies 'git to class!', 'no recess for you!'
secondPeriod.doAlerts.secondAlert()
```